# react jsx debug in chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, electron, reactjs

I am using Electron (Node.js 7.4, chromium 51) with the chrome dev tools (with react and redux extensions)

I can see the react code in the react tab, but when I set breakpoints in the JSX source, and (hit them) they are not properly mapped.

I am using babel with inline source maps, so I can see the output js (es2015 preset and react presets).

I am not using a bundler (since this is an Electron project)

Has anyone else come across this?

**package.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Main Electron Process",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "."
            ],
            "env": {},
            "sourceMaps": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/NodeWork//window.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

**launch.json** (I use VSCODE)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Main Electron Process",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "."
            ],
            "env": {},
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
```

Comment: You can still use bundlers in Electron projects if you like. It's still a web app running in a browser-like env. It might be more helpful if we could see the config. Do you use [electron-compile](https://github.com/electron/electron-compile)? Do you see any of the original source, or just the transpiled source?

Comment: @Gideon, I don't use bundlers, since I don't see the need for them in electron. I will add the package.json. I can see both the original and the transpiled code. And yes, I really like electron-compile, but I have not been able to install it, so I am still using Babel with a watch flag. See: https://github.com/electron/electron-compile/issues/170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading the render page from http:// instead of file://